# How do I search for a string that is not inside quotation marks?

Tags: c#, regex, string, search

i would like to search for a string lets say for "//bazinga" but only if it is not inside quotation marks (single or double).
when i say quotation marks i mean not escaped ones.

for example.

using this as input should return 13  (index of the match found)

```
"the fox is" //bazinga
```

and using this as input should return 18 (since the quotation marks around the string are escaped)

```
"bla bla \"//bazinga\"
```

using this as input should return -1 (not found)

```
"bla bla \"//bazinga"
```

using this as input should return 16 (the first one is inside quotes so dont count)

```
"bla //bzinga"  //bazinga
```

using either of these as input should return -1 (not found)

```
"bbbb //bazinga"
'bbbb //bazinga'
```

Comment: Commas? You escape with forward-slashes? Curious...

Comment: What do you mean by (return 13)? Did you mean string.Length?

Comment: I think he means an IndexOf that ignores values inside quotation marks.

Comment: the location where the match start, 13 chars from begining

Comment: i edited my post, i used / insted of \ to escape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bit of parsing to do that. You can search for either escaped quotation marks, a quoted string, or the text that you want to match, and analyse what you get. Something like:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(
  input,
  "(/\"|/'|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|" + Regex.Escape("//bazinga") + ")"
);
```

By searching for escaped quotation marks, then quoted strings, then the text, you make sure that a quoted string is not escaped, and that the text is not inside a quoted string.

If any of the mathces is your text, you found it.

#### Edit

With this input:

```
string input = "asdf /\" /' '//bazinga'  \"//bazinga\" //bazinga";
```

I ran the match, and then showed the result using:

```
foreach (Match match in matches) {
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", match.Index, match.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
5 /"
8 /'
11 '//bazinga'
24 "//bazinga"
36 //bazinga
```

You can use code like this to get the indexes of the actual hits in the matches collection:

```
int[] found =
  matches.Cast<Match>()
  .Where(m => m.Value == "//bazinga")
  .Select(m => m.Index)
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: this look promising, i have changed my post and added some more examples. at first i put / as an escape char insted of \ , i have fixed that, i will try your proposal.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to have a look to :

[RegEx library for strings](http://www.regxlib.com/Search.aspx?k=string&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20)

It contains a lot of RegEx that you can test directly on the site and change according to your needs. I always use it as source whenever I need to work with RegEx. You can use the single and double quotes as "escape chars" and define your RegEx accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

With this input:

```
This is "bazinga" asdf
```

And this regular expression:

```
["][a-zA-Z\x20]+["]
```

You can run Split instead of Search and get this output:

```
This is
asdf
```

I recommend getting this free tool: Expresso

http://www.ultrapico.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
int getIndexWithoutQ(string find)
{
int index = -1;
string search = "";
for (int i = 0; i < find.Length; i++)
{
while (find[i] == '\"')
 i++;
if (i < find.Length)
  search += find[i];
}

if (search.IndexOf(find) == -1)
   return -1;
while (this.insideQ(all, find, index = all.IndexOf(find)));
return index;
}

bool insideQ(string all, string find, int begin)
{

}
```